# writeAsCSV() and writeAsText() is unexpected

Tags: scala, writetofile, apache-flink

I am using apache flink via the Scala API and at some point I obtain a  `DataSet[(Int, Int, Int)]`. The result of using the methods  `writeAsCSV()` and  `writeAsText()` is unexpected. It creates a directory. That directory has as location and name the first parameter of the method call (e.g.  `filePath` .) In that directory two files emerge with names "1" and "2". In these files I can see the DataSets data. They seems that the DataSets content is partitioned into these two files.
Trying to recreate this behavior to show a more concise code fragment I could not. That is I witnessed the creation of one file with the expected name at the expected position and no creation of a directory.
    val mas = ma_ groupBy(0,1) sum(2)
    mas.writeAsCsv("c:\flink\mas.csv" )

results in the creation of a directory with the name "mas.csv" and two files in it "1" and "2". When does something like this happen? 
Used flink 9.1  local mode, Windows 7, scala 2.10, eclipse3.0.3

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behavior. If you want to get a single output file, you need to set the parallelism for the sink to one.

```
dataset = dataset.writeAsCsv("filename").setParallelism(1);
```

For DataStream API, you need to insert an additional `rebalane()` to break the operator chain. Otherwise, the whole chain will be executed with dop=1 or `setParallelism()` might be ignored.

```
datastream = datastream.rebalance().writeAsCsv("filename").setParallelism(1);
```

Comment: `rebalance` is only required for the DataStream API. If you change the DOP of an operator in the DataSet API, the data will be automatically distributed among the subsequent operators.